# Opening a file from a parent form into a child form's text box C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, text-editor, mdi, openfiledialog

I'm new at c# and I'm having some difficulties with a project I'm doing. I have a mdi program with two forms. I need to open a file into a richTextBox in the child form (Form2) from the MenuStrip in the parent form (Form1). How do I get the richTextBox from the child form using a method from the parent form?  I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. The following is the code on my parent form. Thanks!

```
   private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "";
        if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.MdiParent = this;
            f2.Show();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: You can expose a property to hold the file data on the second form and then when you show the second form you populate the property. When form2 loads it checks the property and fills itself in.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

One way is to add the file name to the constructor of the child form.  Thus your main form would contain

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(openFileDialog1.FileName);
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

and then in the child form's constructor, define this:

```
public void Form2(string fileName);
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    this.RichTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

The above is a sensible option if the child form cannot legally be shown without an associated file name, because you force the caller to provide the file name when constructing it.

If the child form has a fileless mode (e.g. when creating a new document) you can use a different method.  Provide a public property for the file name.

Parent:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2()
f2.OpenFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

Child:

```
public void OpenFile(string fileName);
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    this.RichTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

Finally, if you'd rather have the file I/O logic in the MDI class, you can just expose the textbox:

Parent:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2()
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
f2.DocumentText = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

Child:

```
public string DocumentText
{
    set
    {
        this.RichTextBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

One advantage of passing the file name instead of the text is you can set the window's title bar to show the file name.

Child:

```
public void Form2(string fileName);
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    this.RichTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    this.Text = String.Format("NotePad -- {0}", fileName); //Title
    sr.Close();
}
```

or

```
public void OpenFile(string fileName);
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    this.RichTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    this.Text = String.Format("NotePad -- {0}", fileName); //Title
}
```

Comment: OK, I'm still doing something wrong. The openFileDialog works fine, and it opens a new Form2 (child form), but it doesn't read the file I select. It just opens a new Form 2
StreamReader fileStreamReader;
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
ofd.Title = "Select File";
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
fileStreamReader = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
f2.openFileText = fileStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
fileStreamReader.Close();}

Answer (score 1):

This line of code appears to be setting the `Text` property of `Form1`, which isn't what you want.

```
Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Create a public property in `Form2` that sets the `RichTextBox.Text` property:

```
public string SomeText   // name it something more appropriate :)
{
    set { RichTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Then you can change the first line above to the following, which will send the text to the `RichTextBox` control in `Form2`:

```
f2.SomeText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

//I have a solution for it dont know if its a best practice or not but it works for me.

private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Opens a file into the child form rich text box.

```
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = "Open File",
            Filter = "CNC Files (*.nc)|*.nc|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        };

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
        ChildForm cf = new ChildForm
        {
            MdiParent = this
        };

        {
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName));
            cf.richTextBox1.Text = read.ReadToEnd();
            cf.Text = open.FileName;
            read.Dispose();
            read.Close();
            cf.Show();
            cf.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            //achieved.
        }
```